# why carry flag is turned on in this subtraction

Tags: assembly, binary

```
=    6   -    9
= 00000110-00001001 
= 00000110+(11110110+1)
= 00000110+11110111
= 11111101
```

here we can't see carry so how the carry flag is turned on?
   I'm newbie to programming

Comment: Because the top bit borrows.

Comment: There are plenty of existing resources that explain binary arithmetic

Comment: The result of the addition should be 9 bits with the 9th being the carry. If you do it properly you will see it's `1`.

Comment: you are using signed binary, take a look at the answer below...

Comment: See http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2343/10f/notes/040_overflow.txt (linked from the x86 tag wiki, but maybe it should be added to the "binary" tag wiki, too)

Answer (score 1):

a - b = a + (-b)  and we know that for twos complement you invert and add one to negate a number so a - b = a + (~b) + 1

```
      1 
 000110
+110110
=======
```

so filling that in

```
 001101 
 000110
+110110
========
 111101
```

and your carry out is a 0 which means there was a borrow, I assume you are on an x86?  sometimes carry out is inverted to indicate borrow with a 1 vs just carry.  (just like you invert the carry in and second operand on the way in).

but even simpler 6 - 9 means you have to borrow so the result has the carry flag indicate a borrow in whatever way your processor indicates that some indicate a carry of 1 is borrow some dont invert and a carry of 0 is borrow.  likewise the subtract with borrow if you have one can be cascaded on the first subtract or prior subtract with borrows for wider math.

and 6 - 9 = -3 which is 111111....1111101 or take 3 (0b11) invert and add one  1111..11100 + 1 = 11111...111101.   so the expected result is 11111...111101 with an indication of borrow.